# Flutter: flutter_swiper package control space between slides

Tags: flutter

I am using `flutter_swiper` package in my app. I have following code:

```
Container(
    height: size.getSizePx(200),
    child: Swiper(
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              height: size.getSizePx(200),
              child: Image.network(imageList[index].thumb),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: imageList.length,
      ),
)
```

Image size that comes server is normally `370x276`

**Problem**

Swiper works very well, but space between two images is very big. Is there any how I can control the spaces between Swiper slides (images)?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Have you solved the issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @Kavindhi unfortunately not